# Different Java file name than the class name in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java

I am at the beginner level in JAVA and finding difficulty in understanding this scenario.

I have read that, the name of the class should match the name of the file that holds the program. In the attached image, i have two classes and the name of the class file is different than that of classes having the program.

When compiled in cmd it shows error as expected, but why the Eclipse compiler not giving any error here ?

[Eclipse Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxMXZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no error during compilation either in cmd or eclipse. Since you are new for this. You need to have a look what is **public class and class**.

I would rather said that the filename and the class name is must have same name but not strict. Well since you are beginner, just understand this. When you get familiar with java, you can go digging about the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)

Here explanation that might be can help you to understand.

I create similar project like yours.

[image]

So you see there is a A.java but contain Box and BoxDemo class inside A.java. What happen when you compile? Below is the generated class file when you compile.

[image]

There is no A.class. Why? you should read about more public class and class just like i mention.

Below is the another example java class.

[image]

And below is the generated class files.

[image]

Hope this help you to understand how it works.

Comment: Thank you. So from your comment i learnt that, as long as the class is not public the file name is need not to be matched with the class name. Could you provide any reference or any reading material which tells the logic of this behavior. I will be great full to you.

Answer (score 0):

In java, It doesn't need to match the name of the class and the name of the file that holds the program. When the class is public, then it should be same name for the class name and the source file name.